# How to subset a map in clojure?

Tags: clojure

What is the idiomatic clojure for `subset`:

```
user=> (subset [:a :b] {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
{:a 1 :b 2}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the `select-keys` function:

```
user=>  (select-keys {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} [:a :b])
{:b 2, :a 1}
```